# Not all Q&A dialogs have been made responsive yet

Tags: feature-request, popups, responsive-design

Almost all dialogs on the Q&A pages have been made responsive. I've found one exception (but maybe there are more) among the rarely used ones, e.g. the one you get when voting to delete a question which is used as an original for duplicates:

> #### This question cannot be deleted
>
> This question cannot be deleted because other questions are linked as duplicates of this one.
>
> Those posts must be deleted - or reopened, if they are not truly duplicates - before this question can be deleted.

If you have 20k reputation on Meta Stack Exchange, you can test it on e.g. [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38411/295232). When viewing this dialog on screens with a small width, it's cut off:

[image]

Comment: From my experience, most of the "moderator related dialogues" haven't been made responsive yet. Like the one you get when you flag something (which is, really, really, really, annoying since my favorite SE site as a lot of things that need flagging)

Comment: The flagging dialog doesn't have the new 'Stacks' design, but it *is* responsive.

Comment: Oh, I just tested again and that's true. It's just hardcore difficult to flag comments on my phone (so, I guess, don't mind what I said?)