# Vote to delete via mobile web doesn't check for duplicates

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, mobile-web, vote-to-delete

I've just voted to delete [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37937/what-do-you-think-should-happen-when-the-500-000th-question-is-asked) even though it's [used as the original question for a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337436/295232), namely [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38411/295232).

The popup informing you that it can't be deleted isn't shown on the (old) mobile web version of Stack Exchange; that just votes to delete it straight away.